# Массив заполняется числами -858993460

Tags: c++, массивы, матрицы

Задача состояла в том, что бы в каждой строке матрицы найти произведение чисел между максимальным и минимальным членами, а если нельзя высчитать (рядом стоят) - то вывести 0.

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "math.h"
#include "iostream"
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int k, l;
    int mas[12][14];
    cout << "Enter Lenth:\t";
    //cin >> l;
    l = 2;
    cout << "Enter Width:\t\n";
    //cin >> k;
    k = 2;
    //+++++++++Ввод эл массива
    for (int i = 0; i < k; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < l; j++) {
            cin >> mas[k][l];
        }
    }
    //OOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOO
    for (int i = 0; i < k; i++) {//1 итерация на 1ну строку на экране

        int min = mas[i][1];    //мин и макс элементы
        int max = mas[i][1];    //
        int minN = 1;           //Номера мин и
        int maxN = 1;           //макс элементов
        int proiz = 1;
        for (int j = 0; j < l; j++) {       //сканирование на минимальные члены в строке(в l)
            if (min > mas[i][j]) { min = mas[i][j]; minN = j; }
            if (max < mas[i][j]) { max = mas[i][j]; maxN = j; }
        }
        for (int g = 0; g < l; g++) { cout << mas[i][g] << " "; } //вывод строки
        cout << "\t";
        if (abs(minN - maxN) > 1) {         //условие, при которм произведение существует

            if (minN < maxN) {
                for (int y = minN+1; y < maxN; y++) { //вычисление произведения
                    proiz *= mas[i][y];}
            }
            else for (int y = maxN+1; y < minN; y++) {
                proiz *= mas[i][y]; } //тоже вычисление произведения
        }

        else { proiz = 0; }     //0
        cout << proiz << " " << min << " " << max<<" "<<minN<<" "<<maxN<< endl; //Вывод конца строки - произв, мин, макс
    }
    return 0;
}
```

[image]

Comment: Берите отладчик и отлаживайте. Это ваше число - сборище байтов 0xCC, что явно говорит о неинициализированной памяти или выходе за границы массива.

Comment: Что, по Вашей задумке, должна делать вот эта строка внутри цикла? `cin >> mas[k][l];`

Comment: Для начала надо убрать весь рунглиш из программы.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

У вас индексы в инициализации массива попутаны

```
for (int i = 0; i < k; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < l; j++) {
            cin >> mas[k][l];
        }
    }
```

Должно быть

```
for (int i = 0; i < k; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < l; j++) {
            cin >> mas[i][j];
        }
    }
```

Заметил непотребство @Yaant

Ну и с поиском минимума и максимума ерунда, но эта ерунда работоспособна. Вот как надо:

```
int min = mas[i][0];    
int max = mas[i][0];    
int minN = 0;           
int maxN = 0;           
int proiz = 1;
for (int j = 1; j < l; j++) {
            ///Если здесь минимум больше какого-то значения, то с чего это большее значение вдруг становится минимумом?
            if (min > mas[i][j]) { min = mas[i][j]; minN = j; }
            ///Если здесь максимум меньше какого-то значения, то с чего это меньшее значение вдруг становится максимумом?
            if (max < mas[i][j]) { max = mas[i][j]; maxN = j; }
        }
```

Идея состоит в том, что в качестве кандидата на минимум берется элемент с индексом 0, (массивы в C++ считаются с 0), а поиск идет с первого элемента. Экономия одного сравнения.